# automating the solr index mechanism

Tags: solr

I have indexed few PDF files in solr. I have used curl command for now. My requirment is that if files are pushed to a perticular directory, those files must be indexed. no manual indexing should be done. When files come, it must be indexed. Is there any way to achieve this ? I am new to Solr. Pls give brief suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see 2 options.

1. Create cron job (or something like that)
2. Try to use [DataImportHandler's scheduler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Scheduling)

I would probably lean more towards cron(like) solution 1.
That way after file got indexed it can be moved to separate folder. This is very basic solution, using proper queueing system should give you option to process many files at once.

Comment: Thanks Fuxi.. Is there a way that i can integrate solr with hadoop and programatically can I automate it? I have just heard about it. If you got any idea on this pls do share & help me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any practical experience with Hadoop. Do you plan to use Hadoop to index stuff in Solr? If so there is a Java client for Solr that you can use. Then it's over to Hadoop to start the task.

Comment: Yes. I want hadoop to index the files in solr

Comment: So just create hadopp job (or however you call it) and use https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj (or other library) to push data to Solr